# How do you call GetMethod for a generic function that takes a generic parameter (without using GetMethods)?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

I know I can fetch the method info using `GetMethods`, but I want to know how to do it properly without `GetMethods`. I have read other SO questions and answers that suggest this is not possible, or suggest just using LINQ instead, but that isn't really an answer to the question.

Consider at the most basic level, a static generic function that takes a single generic parameter.

```
private static void Test<T>(T val)
{
}
```

To fetch this method info we can just call `Type.GetMethod("Test", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic)`. However if there were some reason we could not use this simple `GetMethod` signature (perhaps due to multiple overloads), then we need to supply the parameter types. The problem is that I cannot create a parameter type that accurately matches the `T val` parameter. What's interesting is that I can take the parameters from the method info (fetched with `GetMethods`) and pass that into `GetMethod` to get the desired outcome. This means that if it were only possible to create the appropriate generic types (with `IsGenericParameter` set to true) then I feel like this would be completely possible.

So that means that this is entirely possible in .NET, and only require the creation of the proper type instances. How does one create these type instances? And if they are not possible to create, why aren't they?

I created [a simple fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/quVZd6) to showcase the issue.

Comment: Your best bet is `GetMethods()` and filter/search inside the results...

Comment: Sorry if GetMethods()` not being an acceptable answer was not clear before (I updated the title to be more clear), it is a bit tough to word this question properly. Really, the root issue is about creating generic type parameters, but I'm open to any answer that is specific to `GetMethod()` because that is the entry point to the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It isn't readily available, because the types you need are actually generic type arguments that **only exist** in the method / parameter definition. For example, in your `Test<T>(T val)`, the parameter type is "the `T` as defined by `Test<T>`. You can't *construct* that, because it isn't composed *from* anything. The only way to obtain that `T` is via `GetParameters()`.

Basically, that leaves: *the hard way* - i.e. manually. For example:

```
var method1 = typeof(Program).GetMethods(flags).Single(x => x.Name == "Test"
     && x.IsGenericMethodDefinition && x.GetParameters().Length == 1
      && x.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType == x.GetGenericArguments()[0])
    .MakeGenericMethod(paramTypes1);
```

Obviously it is simpler if you know there is only one `Test(...)` method:

```
var method = typeof(Program).GetMethod("Test", flags)
    .MakeGenericMethod(paramTypes1);
```

Comment: Yea those two scenarios are trivial, but if there were some way to produce a `Type.GenericTypeParameter` the scenario described in my questions would also be trivial.

Comment: @pjs and: there isn't. The types required only exist *inside* the method definition - to reference the parameter types of a generic method you *have* to use `GetParameters()` etc. Sorry, but that's the way it is.

Comment: That's a great point that I haven't read about yet, that the types themselves are not accessible because they are defined within the method definition they are a part of. Thanks for this!

Comment: I feel like your comment is essentially the answer to this question (i.e. not possible **because** you cannot access the type information required). If you want to reword that as an answer I will accept it for you.

Comment: @pjs expended accordingly

Comment: We now have https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.makegenericmethodparameter?view=net-7.0 so maybe this answer should be updated

Answer (score 3):

This isn't calling GetMethod but the "other" way to get a generic method definition is to "cast" a method group to a specific type, then call `.Method.GetGenericDefinition()` on it.

In your example, the method signature you need is `Action<object>` where object is just a placeholder and can be any type that matches the constraints of your generic method.

```
var genericMethodDefinition =
    ((Action<object>)Test<object>).Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition();
```

You might select a different overload of "Test" that is defined as `private static T Test<T>(T val, int counter)` by using the following.

```
var genericMethodDefinition2 =
    ((Func<object, int, object>)Test<object>).Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition();
```

Comment: Hmm, that approach has one drawback - it doesn't sue one of great feature that reflection give to us - the name of method `Test` is hardcoded. It cannot be stored as `string` f.e.

Comment: Depending on your application, that might be a drawback or an advantage.

Comment: This is definitely the most interesting answer I've seen yet. It unfortunately does not answer the question specifically (as @pwas mentioned), but it is certainly very creative and most definitely worthy of mention. `var paramTypes = ((Action<object>)Test<object>).Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition().GetParameters().Select(x => x.ParameterType).ToArray();`

Comment: So handy and Smart!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't think that it is possible.
But other approach (still hard way, I believe that `GetMethods` would be better):

```
var method1 =
    typeof (Program).GetMember("Test*",
                               BindingFlags.InvokeMethod |
                               BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                               BindingFlags.Static)
                    .Cast<MethodInfo>()
                    .Single(
                            m =>
                            m.GetGenericArguments().Length == 1 &&
                            m.GetGenericArguments()[0].IsGenericParameter)
                    .MakeGenericMethod(paramTypes1);
```

Of course, you can omit `MakeGenericMethod` to get exacly the same result as `method2`.

Comment: I have not heard of globbing `GetMember` names before, interesting idea. Sadly, this method is basically the same as `GetMethods` just using a different API (i.e. filtering a list of results rather than matching a specific signature).

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but for future reference the following also works with .NET core

```
var flags = BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
//the 0 indicates the index of the parameter
var paramTypes1 = new[] { Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter(0) };

var method = typeof(Program).GetMethod("Test", 1, flags, null, paramTypes1, null);
```

or simply

```
var method = typeof(Program).GetMethod("Test", 1,  paramTypes1);
```

Suppose the method signature was

```
Test<T>(string val)
```

Then the paramTypes1 changes to

```
var paramTypes1 = new[] {typeof(string), Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter(0) };
```

even if the generic isn't a parameter per say it still needs to be mentioned in the array