# C# How to use GetMethod to find a specific overload with a generic out parameter?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, getmethod

Everything is in the title, but let me put some code.
Let's say we have a class with 2 methods with the same name:

```
class MyClass
{
  /// <summary>
  /// The first version
  /// </summary>
  public TItem Foo(long param1) { ... }
  /// <summary>
  /// Overload with a generic parameters
  /// </summary>
  public bool Foo<TItem>(out TItem item, long param1) { ... }
}
```

An we need to get the MethodInfo for the second 'Foo' method which has a generic out parameter:

```
    public class AnotherClass
    {
      public MethodInfo GetFooForType(Type typeOfItem)
      {
        // the answer is probably GetMethod with the right parameters
        return typeof(MyClass).GetMethod(???);
      }
    }
```

Please note that:

- I'm trying to NOT USE GetMethods or GetMember because it's inelegant and prone-to-future-errors
- Renaming any of the Foo methods is not an option (would be too easy).
- The type or TItem is obviously known only at runtime.
- I'm probably looking for the right parameters for GetMethod, but I can take any suggestion (other that GetMethods or GetMember).
- I spent 1 hour searching StackOverflow for the answer without success, but reflection evolved so much that there is a lot of irrelevant answers all around. Adding a date filter in stackoverflow might be a great idea (or maybe a .Net framework version filter ?)
- You are more than welcome to prove me wrong an find me the obvious answer I missed !
- This is not a .Net Core project (MakeGenericMethodParameter is not an option)
- My name is Mose and I'm a bullet addict ^^

Comment: "...find an overload with a generic out parameter" could return multiple results. The easiest mechanism is to use `GetMethods` and filter on the name as well as the parameters and then return `MethodInfo[]` or return `MethodInfo` with an exception if there are multiple matches similary to `GetMethod`.

Comment: Where does the first version get `TItem` from ? I think you need to include more context for the two methods.

Comment: Try `type.GetMethod("Foo", new[] { Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter(0).MakeByRefType(), typeof(long) })`

Comment: Added more context.  And I am trying to AVOID GetMethod. TItem can be anything, it's a generic parameter for the method and not the declaring type.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer to your question (with all its caveats) is "you can't do that".  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29904239/3791245) from Marc Gravell in 2015.  The short version is that the types required for the overload to Type.GetMethod only exist inside the method definition.  You can't create the right generic parameter type until you already have the method!  If you made MyClass generic (e.g. `MyClass<TItem>`), now you could get somewhere with Type.GetMethod, because now you _can_ create the correct generic type (per the first part of the answer from @GuruStron).

Answer (score 3):

If your class is a generic one (and if it is not, your code will give you a warning about overriding) you can use `typeof(MyClass<>).GetGenericArguments().First().MakeByRefType()`:

```
class MyClass<TItem>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The first version
    /// </summary>
    public TItem Foo(long param1) { throw new Exception(); }
    /// <summary>
    /// Overload with a generic parameters
    /// </summary>
    public bool Foo(out TItem item, long param1) { throw new Exception();}
}

var genericMI = typeof(MyClass<>).GetMethod(
    "Foo",
    new[] 
    { 
         typeof(MyClass<>).GetGenericArguments().First().MakeByRefType(), 
         typeof(long)
    });
```

For non-generic you can use `Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter(0).MakeByRefType()` (actually it will work with `MyClass<T>` and override of generic parameter in `Foo<T>` too):

```
class MyClass
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The first version
    /// </summary>
    public int Foo(long param1) { throw new Exception(); }
    /// <summary>
    /// Overload with a generic parameters
    /// </summary>
    public bool Foo<TItem>(out TItem item, long param1) { throw new Exception();}
}

var genericMI = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod(
        "Foo",
        new[] 
        {
            Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter(0).MakeByRefType(),
            typeof(long)
        });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, TItem is a generic parameter of the method, not the declaring type. I added a lot of context to make that clear. And sadly I cannot use .Net Core...

Comment: @Mose Yes, it's method from .NET Core. also code in the question will not compile.