# Why can't I look up a specific generic method by its parameter types?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

The `System.Linq.Queryable` type has a method named `Contains` with two overloads:

- `bool Contains<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource>, TSource)`
- `bool Contains<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource>, TSource, IEqualityComparer<TSource>?)`

I want to get the first overload, so I use the following code:

```cs
var queryableContainsMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethod(
    nameof(Queryable.Contains),
    new[] { typeof(IQueryable<T>), typeof(T), });
```

But this returns `null`. **Why?**

---

**NOTE:** I am not asking *how* to get a reference to this method; I am asking *why* the code that I expect to give me said reference, does not.

Comment: I expect the issue is that the method itself is generic.

Comment: @vc74 @PanagiotisKanavos Are the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getmethod?view=net-7.0#system-type-getmethod(system-string-system-type())) wrong? The top of the remarks section for the overload OP is using states: _"The search for `name` is case-sensitive. The search includes public static and public instance methods."_, so I would expect static methods to be included without specifying binding flags. [In testing](https://rextester.com/MSERB51521), that does indeed seem to be the case.

Comment: what is `T` in your calling code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you call GetMethod for a generic function that takes a generic parameter (without using GetMethods)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29904106/how-do-you-call-getmethod-for-a-generic-function-that-takes-a-generic-parameter)

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain It's from the enclosing type. Which is part of the problem, since if I wasn't inside a generic type I'd have no way to specify `typeof(T)`, and AFAIK in C# there's no way to get a reference to an unbounded generic type (you can get an unbounded reference to a type that _uses_ generics, but that's not the same thing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that the parameters are generic while `IQueryable<T>` is not, for reflection purposes. It uses the `T` type of the enclosing method.

Unlike what I assumed, there's no need to specify `Static` in the binding flags.

It's possible to use `typeof` on a generic type by omitting the type parameters, eg `typeof(IQueryable<>)`

Borrowing from this [similar question about OrderBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269578/get-a-generic-method-without-using-getmethods), the following snippet can retrieve the `Contains(TSource)` overload:

```
var TSource = Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter(0);

var method=typeof(Queryable).GetMethod(
    nameof(Queryable.Contains),
    new[] { 
        typeof(IQueryable<>).MakeGenericType(TSource), 
        TSource 
    }
);
```

To get the second, we need to specify the `IEqualityComparer<>` parameter too:

```
var TSource = Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter(0);

var method=typeof(Queryable).GetMethod(
    nameof(Queryable.Contains),
    new[] { 
        typeof(IQueryable<>).MakeGenericType(TSource), 
        TSource,
        typeof(IEqualityComparer<>).MakeGenericType(TSource)
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you sir! I really did try searching for this topic, but Google is becoming so cluttered with spam and sites that are just using SO data with different SEO, and the SO search is and always has been useless, thus I resorted to posting this question.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that it is due to the generic type argument.

`T` will resolve to a specific type at runtime. So if `T` is an `int` it will look for a method with the signature `Contains<int>(this IQueryable<int>, int)`. But no such method exists. You instead need to look for a generic method, without specifying the actual type of the generic method parameter type.

I'm not sure exactly how you should write that, but reflection with generic types tend to be even more complicated than regular reflection. There are a bunch of of reflection methods, like [MakeGenericMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod?view=net-7.0) to help convert from or to an open generic type and a type with the generic parameters specified.

As various commenters have noted, specifying binding flags might also be needed, but I would think you also need handle the generic types some other way.

Comment: That's the problem indeed. `GetMethod` will work even without binding flags once the parameters are correct